# Using modrewrite, would like to separate base url, request uri, and get arguments

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the modrewrite:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which adds the original request uri into an index.php request path if the file does not exist. With some $_SERVER manipulation, I can then get the request. But it requires a lot of code, since $_SERVER is populated differently between different servers.

I would like to instead separate the url like this. If I have an url:

```
www.test.com/somedir/foo/bar?this=that
```

and the htaccess file is located at `www.test.com/somedir/`, I would like the resulting url to be:

```
www.test.com/somedir/index.php?r=foo/bar&this=that
```

on the other hand, if there were no get variables at the end of the original url, like this:

```
www.test.com/somedir/foo/bar
```

I would like to get this instead:

```
www.test.com/somedir/index.php?r=foo/bar
```

I have tried to play around with this, but just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule .* index.php?r=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: close, but not quite what I wanted. With this rewrite, `somedir/` gets included in the r variable, but I only want the part of the request uri after the base directory. so if the request is `www.test.com/somedir/foo/bar` and the htaccess file is in the directory `www.test.com/somedir/`, I only want r to container `foo/bar`, but this rewrite contains `somedir/foo/bar`.

Comment: Have you tried using `RewriteBase` or `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somedir(/.*)$`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the QSA flag, which appends to the query string instead of replacing it.